# jQuery and clip-path css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have big difficulty to assign the css clip-path using jQuery. For exemple I tried:

```
$("#mydiv").css({ "clip-path": "inset(10% 10% 10% 10%)" });
```

the result in the style of div is `null`. I tried with many values (`px`, `%`) and tried to assign in the `img`, all for the same result: `null`.

To assign the old CSS `clip` is working fine, but not `clip-path`. Does anyone know of a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML.

Comment: clip-path is something that Mozilla wants and could help, but only Firefox supports it.